# SortedDictionary throws "same key already exists" with two different entries

Tags: c#

I have two strings, they are not equal :

```
   var filename1 = "Statuts PE signés.pdf";
   var filename2 = "Statuts PE signés.pdf";
```

The characters for filename1 :

```
[0] S= 83
[1] t=116
[2] a=97
[3] t=116
[4] u=117
[5] t=116
[6] s=115
[7]  =32
[8] P=80
[9] E=69
[10]  =32
[11] s=115
[12] i=105
[13] g=103
[14] n=110
[15] e=101
[16] ´=769
[17] s=115
[18] .=46
[19] p=112
[20] d=100
[21] f=102
```

The characters for filename2 :

```
[0] S=83
[1] t=116
[2] a=97
[3] t=116
[4] u=117
[5] t=116
[6] s=115
[7]  =32
[8] P=80
[9] E=69
[10]  =32
[11] s=115
[12] i=105
[13] g=103
[14] n=110
[15] é=233
[16] s=115
[17] .=46
[18] p=112
[19] d=100
[20] f=102
```

I can add this two entries in a Dictionary :

```
var files1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
files1.Add(filename1, 1);
files1.Add(filename2, 2); // OK
```

But when I try with a SortedDictionary, I get "ArgumentException : An entry with the same key already exists" :

```
var files2 = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
files2.Add(filename1, 1);
files2.Add(filename2, 2); // throw "ArgumentException : An entry with the same key already exists"
```

Why ?

Comment: I'm guessing some equals override or == operator. If you call GetHashCode() on the strings you get different vales. I'm not sure what the repercussions are of this workaround -> `var files2 = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
            files2.Add(filename1.GetHashCode(), 1);
            files2.Add(filename2.GetHashCode(), 2);`. Use at own risk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because by default `Dictionary<string, TValue>` uses `EqualityComparer<string>.Default`, which considers `filename1` and `filename2` different because it uses ordinal comparison. On the other hand, `SortedDictionary<string, TValue>` uses `Comparer<string>.Default`, which uses invariant comparison, which considers these strings equal:

```
Console.WriteLine(filename1 == filename2); // false
Console.WriteLine(EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(filename1, filename2)); // false
Console.WriteLine(Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(filename1, filename2) == 0); // true
```

You can enforce ordinal comparison also for `SortedDictionary` by passing `StringComparer.Ordinal` to the constructor:

```
Console.WriteLine(StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(filename1, filename2) == 0); // false
```